# json for jquery tmpl

Tags: jquery, json

can i use this format JSON with jquery template?

```
{
  "ROWCOUNT": 3,
  "COLUMNS": [
    "UTCODICE",
    "UT__NOME",
    "UT__COGN"
  ],
  "DATA": {
    "UTCODICE": [
      1088,
      1087,
      1086
    ],
    "UT__NOME": [
      'Roberto',
      'Paolo',
      'Carlo'
    ],
    "UT__COGN": [
      'Gino',
      'Luigi',
      'Luca'
    ]
  }
}
```

... or...

```
{
  "COLUMNS": [
    "UTCODICE",
    "UT__NOME",
    "UT__COGN"
  ],
  "DATA": [
    [
      1088,
      'Roberto',
      'Gino'
    ],
    [
      1087,
      'Paolo',
      'Luigi'
    ],
    [
      1086,
      'Carlo',
      'Luca'
    ]
  ]
}
```

how can i say to jquery to start parsing from "DATA" tag?

many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The second one looks like it should work, but you'll want to change all of the single quotes (`'`) to double-quotes (`"`).

There's no way to tell jQuery where to start parsing, it does the whole thing in one shot.  However, once it's parsed, you should be able to just do:

```
parsed_json.DATA
```

to access the DATA part of the object.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need a copy of JSON2.js

https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js

You can then do this:

```
var oJSON = JSON.parse(data);
var alPeople = oJSON.DATA
```

Where data is the above string

There is a good example here:

http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2010/11/20/reducing-code-by-using-jquery-templates.aspx

e.g essentially:

```
<script id="peopleTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
  //your template here
</script>
<div id="peopleList"></div>
```

and then in your script parse the data using JQuery template

```
$('#peopleTemplate').tmpl(alPeople).appendTo('#peopleList');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this with the second JSON object:

```
<script id="dataTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
{{each DATA}}
<tr>
{{each $value }}
<td>${$value}</td>
{{/each}}
</tr>
{{/each}}
</script>
```

The template above creates a table row (tr) for each array in "DATA", then creates a table cell (td) for each value in each array.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I'm so confused by this answer. Is this some sort of pseudocode?

Comment: No, this is a jquery template (http://api.jquery.com/category/plugins/templates/). You pass your object to this template and it will render HTML output (In this case <tr><td> elements). Does that help?

Comment: yes, that makes sense now.  And now I see that he mentioned a 'jquery template' in his question and maybe this is what he was talking about.  I'm gonna have to bookmark this plugin.  Looks a lot like liquid templates.